# How do we read and pronounce the "X" which are commonly seen in collaborations in advertising?

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

We often see major brand collaborating to launch new products e.g. The North Face X Timberland.

How do we read and pronounce the "X"? Do we say *cross*, *times* or *with*?
[image]

Comment: In the given example, I don't think there is a good way to "read out loud".  Not only the "x", but the logo has no text and is essentially unreadable.  The intention is to create a visual effect, not an implied reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could pronounce it as 'cross'.  *cross* could mean the following.

> cross verb (MIX) [ T ] If you cross a plant or animal with another of a different type, you cause them to breed together in order to produce a new variety (= type of plant or animal).

> cross noun [C] (MIXTURE) a mixture of two different things that have been combined to produce something new: Police dogs are often a cross between a retriever and a German Shepherd.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cross)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can just say:

> The north face *and / X* Timberland

"with" is also useable, but "cross" and "times" are not really showing how there is a collaboration between the two.

Comment: "with" does sounds more natural than "cross/time" since the latter is more commonly used in math